# If a player is significantly behind in time, does it mean he's bound to lose?

Tags: tournament, fide, world-championship, time-control, time-management

Let's focus on FIDE classical chess finals historically.

Caruana is always behind in time control, thinks more, waste more energy.

Statistically speaking, did the players who played faster won more titles? Is Caruana showing signs of weakness?

Comment: Not sure what point you are trying to make. There can be all kinds of reason for being behind in time such as personal time management, the opponent playing a novelty, etc. I would not dare to draw a direct correlation between time used and  and number of titles. Also, how would you measure "time" here? Time until move 30, time per move, time for whole game....?

Comment: @user1583209 I would measure the total time spent in the whole tournament, per player, so lets say Carlsen finished the game and spent 3h in game 1 + time game 2..... etc, the whole tournament, so I just want to check on the time left when the game is done

Comment: @user1583209 the point I'm trying to make is simple, Chess is mathematics and you can observe that good math students finish well before average students, I just want to see if the same applies to chess, it might be  time management but it might also be that is not as good, I just want  to know what statistics say.

Comment: How do you exclude that it is a spurious correlation? I also don't see how your maths example fits in here. Chess players are not asked to find a solution in the shortest amount of time, but to find the *best* solution using all the time that is available to them. Also, the players in your statistics faced different opponents, (in your analogy, different maths problems). How would you compare them...?

Comment: @user1583209 I don't care about the players, I want to know if  the tournament winner is the one who spent less time. I don't care about the player name nor the year he played. All I want to know is: Are the players who spent less time won more? if I get a 70% I get an answer, If it's 50% 50% then my study is a failure

Comment: @user1583209 I expect to see at least 70% of the time the winner to be the one who spent less time, simply because he knows the theory more, the opponent has to figure it out on the board. So I only care about time, and who was the champion, not the name of the player. In statistics you are bound to have exceptions but I don't think it affects the study as a whole

Comment: Still sounds to me like the statistics of #of storks and #of births... Sorry.

Comment: @user1583209 I flagged this question to be deleted, since I asked here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/chess-pgn-with-time-control, after all, I just want data dump, and that site is the right site for that not this one.. . As for what would stats tell? I don't know and don't care, it's a side project for fun in my free time, unless someone already crunched the numbers

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about statistics, but I do know that they are not "bound" to lose. It depends on the position. Is it easy to play, or is it a very sharp, tactical position? Also, is there a time-increment? Often, in classical FIDE games, there is. Based on experience, I can tell you that it can be very stressful being low on time in a long game, even if there is an increment. However, if psychological (personal) influences are ignored, `it very much depends on the position and on the time-increment`.

Comment: I do understand that and I upvoted it because you are right, but I'm only here looking for either stats or championship games PGN with time control, on which I can do stats myself, since it's easy to do if I have the PGN and time spent per game